# Is Pearson's correlation a continuous function?

Tags: limits, statistics, continuity, correlation

the Pearson correlation is an important measure to detect linear association between two random variables, but is it continuous function?

I'm trying see whether the following is true:
$\lim_{C \to c} \rho(X, Z + CY) = \rho(X, Z + cY)$.

where $\rho$ is the Pearson correlation and C, c are scalars.
It seems trivial for me but I couldn't prove it

Comment: What is $C$? a scalar? Isn't then $\rho(X,CY)=\rho(X,Y)$?

Comment: @nejimban you're right. Let me rephrase the question.

Comment: If you go back to the definition of Pearson's correlation coefficient, you just need to check the continuity of $C\mapsto \mathrm{cov}(X,Z+CY)$ and $C\mapsto E[(Z+CY)^2]$. These functions are easily seen to be polynomials in $C$.